# Image within div change on hover?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have it so that an image of a yellow cog sits inside a div with a yellow border and a white background, and then upon hover the cog changes to white and the background changes to yellow. I'm currently setting the first image as the background of the div, and then using div:hover to change the background on hover, however the spacing etc. doesn't quite work and the border doesn't go around the image properly. Is it possible to have it so the image is inside a link rather than as the background of the div? Here is the code I'm using:

HTML:

```
<div id="settings">
    <a href="settings.html"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#settings {
    border: 4px solid #ffff00;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    background: #fff url(img/cog_yellow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#settings:hover {
    background: #ffff00 url(img/cog_white.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please post a fiddle...it helps a lot..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#run here you can make you code and share it with us, so that we get an idea what the problem is..

Comment: `#settings` is just not declared anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible although not very efficient. You can have two images and show and hide them based on hover:

**HTML**

```
<div class="button_link">
  <a href="settings.html"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/50/50"/></a>
  <a href="settings.html"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/60/50"/></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button_link a:last-child{
  display: none;
}

.button_link:hover a:first-child{
  display: none;
}

.button_link:hover a:last-child{
  display: block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/73cqzdgn/1/)

If you can post a fiddle recreating the issue with the images you're using there is probably a more efficient way of doing this with just CSS and no additional HTML involved

**UPDATE**

This is how I would do this, with just CSS:

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/o62wm0ms/1/)

Comment: how would you suggest a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: you would need to recreate this in a fiddle or post a link to your site or something. Without using the actual images you are using it's hard to find a better solution

Comment: this is what i want to happen, except the image will turn white on hover and the black image background won't be there

Comment: @Brand0n_edwards ok if this is what you're looking for then you can check this off as resolved

Comment: I was looking for a more efficient way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
#settings a{
   display:block;
   width:100px; /* adjust your width */
   height:100px;/* adjust your height */
   border: 4px solid #ffff00;
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   background: url(img/cog_yellow.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#settings a:hover {
   background: url(img/cog_white.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```